# How can I permanently change the mac address on a Linux 3.3.8 device without macchanger?

Tags: linux, mac-address

I'm trying to permanently modify my MAC address on a device running Linux 3.3.8 I cannot get macchanger to install either.

When I try it with

```
ifconfig eth0 hw ether [MAC_ADDRESS]
```

I get

```
ifconfig: SIOCSIFHWADDR: Device or resource busy
```

I have ssh'd into the device. The device is on wifi and ethernet. I've connected through wifi and trying to change the ethernet's mac address. I've tried

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig etho hw NEW_MAC
get the error: ifconfig: SIOCSIFHWADDR: Device or resource busy
ifconfig eth0 up
```

ifconfig shows the mac address was updated. However the GUI elements still show the old mac address. Also, the changes are lost after restart.

```
> uname -a 
> Linux (none) 3.3.8-4.2-g8c1f1dd #1 SMP Thu Jun 27 11:30:45 UTC 2019 mips GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

The MAC address should be changed before the system brings up the network interface.

Bring down the interface to test: `ip link set dev eth0 down`, change the MAC address, then `ip link set dev eth0 up`. Verify that the change was carried out, for example by typing `ip link`.

You did not specify your flavor of Linux. Assuming you have a Debian-like system,
to make the change **permanent** you can add a line in `/etc/network/interfaces`.
Locate your eth0 stanza and use the `hwaddress` directive eg:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    hwaddress ether xxxxxxxxx
```

where xxxxxxxxx represents your chosen address. If you prefer a **random address** then you can use `macchanger` and add a line in that same `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    pre-up macchanger -r eth0
```

If your network interface is managed by **Network Manager**, then you can randomize the MAC address for all interfaces or on a per-connection basis. have a look [here](https://riseup.net/en/security/network-security/mac-address) for example or [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/randomize-mac-address-nm/). You can use the `nmcli` utility (or `nmtui`).

Comment: I added more information to my question. I don't have a folder named "network" in etc. Running ip link set dev eth0 down does not return an error but ifconfig shows the device is still up.

Comment: I still don't know which flavor of Linux you are running (eg Debian) or the device ?... you've only mentioned the kernel, but I see a couple of possible issues. If you don't have `/etc/network/interfaces` that could be why `ifconfig` does not work for you. `ip link set eth0 down/up` should work **as root** even if your interface is not properly configured. If you are not root add `sudo` in front of your commands eg `sudo ip link set eth0 down`.To make changes permanent we need to know what network manager you use. What is the output of `nmcli dev status`, if that works for you ?

Comment: nmcli command was not found. I am on a Mag322 IPTV box

Comment: also, ip link set eth0 down did not work

Comment: I did not realize you have an embedded device. It probably uses U-boot (a BIOS substitute). Perhaps you can set the MAC from there. Type `sudo fw_printenv` and see if 1) if that works for you and 2) you see something like `eth1addr` or `ethaddr` in the configuration. Then I would add a new setting like this: `setenv eth1addr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, where xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx represents your chosen address. Assuming you have only one ethernet port I think it would be `eth1addr` but not sure. Ref: [14.2.13. Ethernet Does Not Work](http://www.denx.de/wiki/bin/view/DULG/EthernetDoesNotWork)

Comment: Good and bad news! That worked and I was able to change the mac address (using fw_setenv). However the changes dont get reflected on ifconfig or when I restart the device. (Thank you so much for helping me)

Comment: Can you confirm that `fw_printenv` shows your variable after you set it using `fw_setenv` ? Perhaps your flash memory is protected (just a guess) - see [fw_setenv do not work, fw_printev does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37255800/6843158). I have another idea: check in your `/boot` directory if you see a .txt or .scr file and check the directives it contains. Perhaps the MAC address is already hardcoded somewhere. From the `/boot` directory try perhaps `grep -iR ethaddr` (or eth1addr) and see if you find something in configuration files.

Comment: Yes setting through fw_setenv is reflected when I do fw_printenv. Although ifconfig shows the original value. The /boot directory is empty, not even any hidden files.

Comment: That device seems to have been trimmed down/customized in some way. Using `fw_setenv` try to set **both** `eth1addr` and `ethaddr` eg: `fw_setenv ethaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`. Use a different MAC address for each, (not a multicast MAC address). Reboot and see if that has any impact on your network interface. If one of the MAC addresses worked, then you'll know whether to use `eth1addr` or `ethaddr`. If that still doesn't work, try to pass it on the command line - [How to change a mac address using the command line parameters in the linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49560937/6843158)

Comment: I did it for ethaddr, eth1addr and eth0 (as that was shown in ifconfig). None of them seem to stick. setenv command isnt found. Doing the steps shown in the link via fw_setenv did not work either. I see bootargs set correctly when I print them via fw_printenv. But after reboot they dont work. Although I can see the bootargs in fw_printenv after reboot.

Comment: I downloaded the software image from [here](https://soft.infomir.com/mag322/release/2.20.10r2/). Apparently the networking scheme is rc.network. My suggestion would be to edit the file `/etc/init.d/rc.network-updown`. Scroll down to line #138, you will see: `ip link set dev eth0 up`. That's where interface eth0 is activated. So add this line **before**: `ip link set eth0 address xxxxxxxxx` where xxxxxxxxx represents your chosen address. You could test without rebooting with: `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, but you might be disconnected. Always keep a backup of modified files.

Comment: Wow, you've gone above and beyond in helping out. I tried that. Did not work. However I found this file that has the mac address:  "/sys/class/net/eth0/address". Will modifying this help? I tried to edit it, but I can't seem to be able to do this. I changed the write permission on the file with chmod too.

Comment: Try perhaps line 112 then, before: `/etc/init.d/rc.network-updown start eth0`. I doubt you can directly modify files in /sys/class/ even as root, they are volatile files reflecting the hardware. What happens when you do `ip link set eth0 down` ? Are you connected to the device through console or SSH (on eth0) ?

Comment: Still no luck. Connected via wifi. The device is connected through both eth0 and wifi.

Comment: There is also a file `rc.network` in the same directory. You can try to add your directive there before `ifup eth0` (line #14). But if you can't make it work from the command line even temporarily, there must be something else that is wrong. You can still try `macchanger` after doing `ip link set dev eth0 down`. The interface has to be down to perform a change of MAC address.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to install macchanger on the device. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: rc.network did not work either.

Comment: I am bit short on ideas. I think there is no point messing with the files at the moment if you can't make it work temporarily from the command line. I would rather use the `ip` command than `ifconfig` eg `ip link set eth0 address xxxxxxxxx` to change the MAC address and `ip link` to check the MAC address. Something else you can try is grep the logs and look for strings like `mac address`, `hwaddr`, the literal MAC address, perhaps you will see a process setting the MAC on the interface.

Comment: For a "static" MAC you could also use

    pre-up macchanger -m xx:xx:xx:xx:xx eth0